# Comparing the results for the current time with the epg time

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have got a problem with comparing the times with the EPG time. When my current time show `2017-10-10 01:23:00` and when my EPG time show `2017-10-10 06:00:00` which is `6:00AM` in the morning and my current time show `1:23AM`, it will always get pass on the if statement so I am not sure why.

When I try this:

```
EPG_Time = time.strptime('2017-10-10 01:23AM', '%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p')
EPG_Time = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(EPG_Time))
EPG_Next_time = time.strptime('2017-10-10 06:00AM', '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M%p')
EPG_Next = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(time.mktime(EPG_Next_time))

if EPG_Next <= EPG_Time:
    print "it is time to delete the data from the list..........."
```

It will always get pass on the if statement when my current time is behind the EPG time. I want to get pass on the if statement as only when my current time is equal or greater than the EPG time which it is `06:00AM` or so I can then delete the data from the list.

Can you please show me an example how I can compare my current time with the EPG time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the format strings for `strptime()` are inconsistent with the actual strings. I'm assuming that's a typo.

Secondly `datetime.datetime` includes it's own [`strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) function so you don't need to convert from a time stamp:

```
from datetime import datetime

EPG_Time = datetime.strptime('2017-10-10 01:23AM', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')
EPG_Next = datetime.strptime('2017-10-10 06:00AM', '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p')

if EPG_Next <= EPG_Time:
    print "it is time to delete the data from the list..........."
```

In this case `EPG_Time` comes before `EPG_Next` so the `print` statement is not executed.

The current time can be obtained using `datetime.now()`. Compare that to your EPG time to determine whether you need to perform the required action:

```
if EPG_Next <= datetime.now():
    print "it is time to delete the data from the list..........."
```

Comment: Thank you for this, but when I try this: `if EPG_Next <= datetime.now():` it give me an error: `TypeError: can't compare datetime.datetime to tuple`. Any idea??

Comment: In your case `EPG_Next` does not contain a `datetime` object, it's probably a time tuple like the one returned by `time.mktime(EPG_Next_time)`. Try using the code that I show in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't getting good values out of the parses, because the formatter has an incorrect format.  For both formatters you should be using

```
'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p'
```

The comparison should work fine.

Comment: should I change from `'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p'` to this `'%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p'`??

Comment: @Daniel  Yes, change both formatters to this value: '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p'.  '%d-%m-%Y %I:%M%p' (the second date formatter) is also not going to provide the correct results.

Comment: Ah I see. So thank you very much for your advice. I am going to see what happens from there. If it is works then great!

Comment: @Daniel, awesome, hope your project goes well.

Comment: Thank you, when I try the code you suggested me to use, it will still get pass on the if statement when I have changed from `'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M%p` to this `%Y-%m-%d %I:%M%p` so it doesn't make any difference. Any idea?